# Manipulating JSON Array in PHP Using SQL Data

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I have no idea what I am doing past what I have here in my code already. In the below example I am attempting to have multiple cable types under each Cable Type column and row for each Lane Type, but as you can see only one cable type is being shown for each in the table.

I am trying to create a while loop or something, so that for each Lane Type it will produce as many cable types that are associated with said lane type, then move on to the next lane type doing the same. For lanes 5 and 6 I believe there is only one cable type for it anyway, so those look correct. How can I create a JSON array in PHP to group all the cable types together for each lane type, instead of it just putting every cable type into separate arrays apart from eachother?

What's happening now is even though you see multiple cable types per lane name or type, they are separated and I am wanting to group them together, so if I call array[0] that would be ALL of Lane-1's cable types, array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TbuJ.png) would call all of Lane-2's cable types, etc etc. As of now, array[0] Just calls that first cable_type and not an array of cable types for that lane_name.

****EDIT (refer to my latest comment)****

Current PHP spits out following JSON array

```
{"Lane-1":["PPAHY4614","PPAHY464","HYBP464.01","PPA241807","ADMC1807"],"Lane-2":["HYBP906.1","PPAHY906","HP464.02","PP8HY461"],"Lane-3":["HYBP421","PAADY412"]}
```

OLD IMAGE:
[image]

****WORKING CURRENTLY****
[image]

PHP

```
//Create array
//Define JSON array
$array = array();

//Run SQL for each array value
    $query="(SELECT DISTINCT lane_name,cable_type
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name != '' AND lane_name != 'Shipped')
        UNION
        (SELECT DISTINCT lane_name,gp_cable_type
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name != '' AND lane_name != 'Shipped')
        ORDER BY lane_name";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $array[$row['lane_name']][] = $row['cable_type'];
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/populate_cableTypes.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        //since data length is always 1,iterate through the 17 lane types
        for (var n=1; n<=17; n++) {
            //stringify data so it can be manipulated
            var stringifyTypes = JSON.stringify(data["Lane-"+n]);
            //check first if data is not null before populating
            if (stringifyTypes != null) {
                console.log("Lane-" + n + " string cable types: " + stringifyTypes);
                //replace characters with new line breaks to format data
                var cable_types = stringifyTypes.replace(/,/g, '<br />')
                .replace(/\"/g, "")//backslash for quotes and brackets
                .replace(/\[/g, "")
                .replace(/\]/g, "");

                //Show data in newly generated cable type td column for each lane type
                $('td.Lane-'+n+'.weight').after("<td>" + cable_types + "</td>");

                console.log("Lane-" + n + " formatted cable types: " + cable_types);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your key problem is really your query.  I don't understand why you are querying 17 different times, when you can get all of this data in a single query. Worry about getting the right query first, then worry about getting into a PHP data structure. Also think about your table structure. It seems very odd to have have different columns for cable_type/gp_cable_type if these values are mutually exclusive.  Perhaps a single cable_type column along with a 0/1 value "gp" column to represent whether this is "gp" (whatever that means)

Comment: I query 17 items because there are potentially 17 Lane Types in the DB (Lane-1 through Lane-17) and I wanted to have each data pertain only to that lane type. Also because I do not know any better... I don't like it either, but this was the only way I know of to produce the data.

Comment: As for the "mutually exclusive" data, they need to be in two columns in the SQL DB because that was how this client had it set up. They are different, not the same, but need to be grouped together for this particular instance.

Comment: You know you can just select all "lane types" with one query right? Try something like this and see where it leads you: `SELECT DISTINT lane_name, cable_type, gp_cable_type FROM bundle_lanes ORDER BY bundle ORDER BY lane_name ASC, cable_type ASC, gp_cable_type ASC`

Comment: Yes but that still puts the data into separate JSON object arrays and the reason I have the SQL union in this instance is so that it spits out all cable types and gp_cable_types. I am trying to create one object for lane-1 with all cable types for array 0, then for array 1 it would be the next lane's cable types, and so on.

Comment: That is extremely easy to do when you work with the result set in PHP.  Something along the lines of this inside the fetch loop `$array[$row['lane_name']][] = $row['cable_type']` or `$array[$row['lane_name']][] = $row['gp_cable_type']` depending on which field is set.

Comment: ok, this seems closer to what I want, so instead I used: $array[][$row['lane_name']] = $row['cable_type']; so that I get this [{"Lane-1":"HYBP464.01"},{"Lane-1":"ADMC1807"},{"Lane-1":"HYBP906.1"},{"Lane-1":"PPAHY464"},{"Lane-1":"PPA241807"},{"Lane-1":"PPAHY906"},{"Lane-2":"HYBP464.01"},{"Lane-2":"ADMC1807"},{"Lane-2":"PPAHY464"},{"Lane-2":"PPA241807"},{"Lane-4":"HYBP464.01"},{"Lane-4":"PPAHY464"},{"Lane-5":"HYBP464.01"},...] NOW I just call val[Lane-1] and get all of Lane-1 cabletypes! Issue I have is setting Javascript to iterate correctly... Can only get it to work for one row.

Comment: OK I updated my question with the newest material. It all works! I have one remaining issue... Data length is ALWAYS 1, since the JSON is just one object array with the different lane types; I would like to instead have three object arrays for each lane type, that way the length property would be valid. Instead, I am having to create a workaround by checking first if data is null before populating, since I must iterate through 17 times (there are potentially 17 lane types). Please advise

Comment: Typically, when sending/receiving JSON you are dealing with a single root element (either object of array).  This is because that is the JSON serialization standard.  If you wanted to work with multiple JSON strings, you can do that, just keep in mind that the client wolud need to understand that it can't simply desrialize the response, but would need to actually break it apart and deserialize each individual component.

Comment: So what I have going for the JSON output is "standard?" I would prefer  an output of {"Lane-1":["..."]},{"Lane-2":["..."]},{"Lane-3":["..."]} instead of {"Lane-1":["..."],"Lane-2":["..."],"Lane-3":["..."]} this gives data length of 3, instead of 1, allowing me to iterate through more effectively in my AJAX for loop. How can I produce this output in my PHP or must I manipulate this through JS? Or is what I have now completely ok? I just don't like that I have to do extra, useless iterations and processes.

Comment: In your case, the data structyure you probably want is `[{"Lane-1": ... }, {"Lane-2": ...}]` (note the array wrapper around the entire thing). Though I would argue that all that would do is introduce an additional nesting level. In order to get this structure in JSON you would need to populate each "lane" into a numerically indexed array. The resulting array would have a length of X where X is number of "lane" objects in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)? Much cleaner way to iterate your data

```
 $.each(data, function(index, val){
     var n = index + 1;
     $('.cable_type'+n).text(val['cable_type']);
 });
```

Comment: Great! That correcetd some JS errors, so I am happy about that.  console log groups the cable types and lane name together correctly, but I need to populate that data correctly now for each Lane row under the Cable Type column...